# Create a div that doesn't allow outside CSS to affect inside elements

Tags: html, css

I have to integrate my webpage code into a big project. Entire project code is inside container div which is included inside `<main>` tag. When I add the container div in `<main>` tag, the project css overwrites my css. Is there a way where we can write a div that creates its own css environment and stops from outside css affecting inner tags?

Comment: like a reset css? #yourdivid * { /* reset all css here */ }

Comment: div {all: unset; other_properties: and_values; ... (of your choice)}

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: 
iframe will scope your html, but you will not be able to access dom.

Option 2:

reset CSS with

```
.your-div{
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  }
}
```

Comment: Current requirement i need to have a div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe with the srcdoc attribute. Things inside an iframe are immune to outside css!

```css
iframe {display:block; border:none}

/* css to demonstrate the immune div */

div {color:red; background:yellow; border:solid;}
```

```html
<div>This is a standard div</div>
<iframe srcdoc="<div>This is a framed div, immune to css</div>"></iframe>
```

See [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) on MDN for more info and pitfalls.